# PostgreSQL add X months to a date

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I try to add X month to the current datetime:

```
UPDATE mytable SET thedate=NOW() + INTERVAL '12 month' WHERE id=1
```

But I got:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for timestamp: « NOW() + INTERVAL '12 month' »
```

What should be the correct syntaxe ?

Edit: seems it comes from my PHP prepare/execute syntax

```
    $t = $connect->prepare('UPDATE mytable 
        SET thedate=:duree
        WHERE id=:id');

    $ok = $t->execute([
        ':duree' => "NOW() + INTERVAL '$duree month'",
        ':id'    => $user,
    ]);
```

Comment: Can you share an English error message please?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's update

Comment: Also - what postgres version are you using?

Comment: Yep what you have works for me to.  Perhaps when you simplified your question you eliminated the problem?

Comment: I edit the topic. It seems the problem comes from the PDO syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to bind a variable with a SQL expression, which is not possible. You can only bind literal values. If you'd replace the binds out of what you showed, supposing `$duree = 12`, you'd get some SQL like this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET thedate = 'NOW() + INTERVAL ''12 month'''
    WHERE id=:id
```

Which is clearly not correct, as `'NOW() + INTERVAL ''12 month'''` is not a valid timestamp[tz], hence the error you get now.

As only the number of months is a parameter to you, you could simple multiple it as an integer with `interval '1 month'`:

```
$t = $connect->prepare('UPDATE mytable 
    SET thedate = now() + (:duree  * interval '1 month')
    WHERE id=:id');

$ok = $t->execute([
    ':duree' => $duree,
    ':id'    => $user,
]);
```